# Debugging typescript with source maps and webpack

Tags: debugging, typescript, intellij-idea, webpack, source-maps

I have project written in Typescript and I want to be able to debug it (either in `Chrome Dev Tools` or in `Intellij`).

At first I saw that Typescript's `import` functionality was not supported. So I tried using `Webpack` along with `webpack dev server` but this failed completely. Even though my application was working (due to having a single `bundle.js` file that has all the code) it would be unable to match the code with the given source maps and this making debugging impossible.

After I stopped using webpack I tried adding `require.js` as a dependency to resolve the `require is not defined` error I was getting. That worked but now I'm stuck again and getting this:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

I have no idea why this isn't working. I want to be make my application work (either through webpack or being able to resolve import statements after transpilation) and still be able to debug the code using the typescript-produced source-maps. How can I achieve this?

I'm attaching my config files in case there is something missing there:

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": [
    "scripts/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: [/*'.ts', '.tsx', */'.js']
    },
    entry: './scripts/main.js',
    output: {
        path: '/',
        filename: 'app.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'source-map-loader', enforce: 'pre' }
        ],
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            {test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css"}
        ]
    },
    watch: true
};
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To enable debugging with webpack, add `devtool: "source-map"` to your `webpack.config.js`.

To load files using `require.js`, change `"module": "amd"` in `tsconfig.json`. `require.js` does not support loading `commonjs` modules.

Comment: Big thanks! Both ways actually worked. I can debug both through chrome via `webpack-dev-server` AND through IntelliJ with correctly mapped and transpiled Typescript

Comment: sourcemap can also be in-lined -> devtool: "inline-source-map"

Answer (score 44):

I'm going to post an answer here. This answer may ***not*** work for you (See Step 5). It varies a lot from person to person.  After so many days spent in research, robin-a-meade's post from [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2453) was the one that nailed it.

Before starting, the main problem seems to lie in the source mapping's URL of inside the VS Code Debugging Configuration file, and how it (VS Code) sees the application. This is independent from any back-end stack you're using (E.g Express, .NET Core, Django, etc.). The only thing you need to be aware of, is that Google Chrome successfully loads the generated source map when your application is running.

Used:

- Visual Studio Code ver 1.13.1
- NodeJS 7.4.0
- Windows 10 64-bit
- Webpack 2.5 (Should apply for Webpack 3 as well)
- TypeScript 2.3

**Install the Google Chrome Extension:**

1) Click on the square icon on the left.

2,3) type "Debugger for Chrome" without commas and click install.

[image: Installing Chrome Extension for VS Code]

**Configure the debugger:**

[image: Configuring the debugger]

4) Click on the bug icon.

5) Click on the gear icon. This will open "launch.json" which is used for configuring the debugging in Visual Studio Code.

Now. This is where it gets really tricky. This is the part that it may or may not work for you.

Again, thanks goes to [robin-a-meade from GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2453#issuecomment-269055938) whose code made it work:

6) Enter the following. This is going to launch a Google Chrome instance with `http://localhost` in the URL. Then, it will use the `webpack://` path to search for the Webpack mappings. This is really tricky and you may have to try with different combinations to see which one works.

```
 {
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost, with sourcemaps",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "diagnosticLogging": true,
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack:///./*": "${webRoot}/*"
            }
        }
```

If you're using Firefox, try using this one:

```
{
            "name": "Launch Firefox",
            "type": "firefox",
            "firefoxExecutable": "C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe",
            "request": "launch",
            "reAttach": true,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "sourceMaps": "server",

            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "url":  "webpack:///",
                    "path": "${webRoot}/"
                }
            ],
            "url": "localhost"
        }
```

**Webpack Configuration**
Add:

devtool : "source-map"

To your webpack configuration. This should go under the modules.export object. 
[image: devtool sourcemap in Webpack]

Run/Build the project with Webpack; this should generate the source-map (Check if the source map is generated, otherwise nothing will work!):
[image]

Then you should be ready to go:
Press the "Play button" in the debugging and it should be working!
[image]

[image]

Remember, any file that is ***not imported to your main .js*** file (where you have all of your imports and requires), ***will not be able to have a breakpoint set.***

If that didn't work, check this list of URLs that can help you out.

1. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2453 (Miracle page that helped me out)
2. [Debug webpack bundled node ts with Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36470946/debug-webpack-bundled-node-ts-with-visual-studio-code)
3. [VS Code: "Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36006303/vs-code-breakpoint-ignored-because-generated-code-not-found-error)
4. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug
5. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25349
6. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1223
7. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/issues/40 (Bottom of the page)
8. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42405563/1057052

For generating soruce maps:
[How do I generate sourcemaps when using babel and webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870830/how-do-i-generate-sourcemaps-when-using-babel-and-webpack)

Comment: @Konstantine Would you consider re-marking this as the accepted answer? It's so much more than the current one.

Comment: Also worth noting here -- After you have the bundled.js source map, try and debug it in the browser dev console, that way you know the maps are working properly.

Comment: I had some troubles with the left part of `sourceMapPathOverrides` while having library option in webpack config. The correct one was in the first line of `index.map.js` file. Replacing `index.ts` with a star made it work. It looks like: `"webpack://MyLib/./src/*": "${workspaceFolder}/src/*"`. Also adding `debugger;` line to a `.ts` file helps to see what path the debugger tries to open.