# Trouble debugging React source map files compiled with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, source-maps

**EDIT:** Source Map works in Firefox, but not in Chrome or Edge.

When I'm debugging warnings/errors, I click on the TSX file and it pulls up an obfuscated version of the .ts/tsx file. The following screenshots will help clarify my issue...

When I get a React error like this
[image]

I click on the `/components/AddObject/index.tsx` link and it opens the file in the console, but it looks like this

[image]

Here's what my webpack config looks like (using devTool: 'eval-source-map')

[image]

Any thoughts as to why my source-map file is behaving this way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debugging typescript with source maps and webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42881493/debugging-typescript-with-source-maps-and-webpack)

Comment: Eh. Unfortunately, no, still no luck :(

Comment: you can also enable source-map in tsconfig.json. This works for me in my backend.

More info here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling

Comment: Hmm. No, still no luck. I just added an edit - source map works in Firefox, but not in Chrome or Edge. I guess I need to go back to the drawing board.

Comment: did you try with simply eval ?